# Android: Running background service without need to run application. Is it possible?

Tags: android, react-native

I am creating an application that should show some Screen on incoming message.

I think I need some background job/service that's running permanently while phone is on. That job will handle for the incoming message and run the Application with some parameters, so based on these parameters the application will show corresponding Screen.

Is it possible to reach the goal this way? Or is there any other ways?

(I am creating the app using react-native, so if there's react-native solution, it would be even better, but native Java-Android solutions are welcome too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is very bad to battery life because it doesn't allow CPU to sleep. There is no guarantee that system will keep your background service alive. For deeper understanding I can suggest you to learn about [services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) and [doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby).

Consider using [Push notifications](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) or at least [job scheduling mecanism](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).